# Where can i download malware variants

Tags: binary-analysis, malware

How/Where can i get variants of a malware ?
The only thing that concerns is that the variants must be a continuous update of the previous one

Comment: No what I meant was "updated variants" of a single malware where as the previous question consists of malware repo's based on their MD5 values.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried AVcaesar @ malware.lu?

Link: https://avcaesar.malware.lu

The Kernelmode.info forum usually hosts malware samples too.